# Getting an average value from MySQL with 2 group by functions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get an average value from my database for a number of different values.

As an example, I am going to use a Purchases table. Our users input the information in different ways. Some of them separate invoices and put them into correct suppliers, others are just inputting a whole value for all of them. The ones that are using the whole value, are easy ones. I know I can just run

```
SELECT store_id, stocktake_id, SUM(cost_value)/COUNT(cost_value) FROM store_purchases GROUP BY store_id ORDER BY store_id DESC
```

And it works fine. However, this query doesn't give correct results for the users that input the invoices separately.

I have tried doing this

```
SELECT store_id, stocktake_id, SUM(cost_value)/(SELECT COUNT(cost_value) FROM store_purchases GROUP BY stocktake_id, store_id) FROM store_purchases GROUP BY store_id ORDER BY store_id DESC
```

But I get an error saying that the subquery returns more than one row. So I tried the following solution

```
SELECT store_id, stocktake_id, SUM(cost_value)/count(DISTINCT stocktake_id) FROM store_purchases GROUP BY store_id ORDER BY store_id DESC
```

Is this the correct way to go about it? Here is a sample screenshot of the results that I get from store_purchases for a store that inputs invoices separately [image]

Is this the correct approach or is there a better way to get this average.

Comment: but you dont select `id,supplier_id` in your query so how you get this result and where is `sum column in your result`?

Comment: and whats the issue in your query?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can try this, use subquery get the `SUM` and `COUNT` result set then `join`

```
SELECT  t1.stocktake_id,t1.store_id, (totalPrice / cnt)
(
    select stocktake_id,sum(store_purchases) totalPrice
    FROM store_purchases
    GROUP BY stocktake_id
)t1 
join 
(
    select stocktake_id,store_id,count(store_purchases) cnt
    FROM store_purchases
    GROUP BY stocktake_id, store_id
)t2 on t1.stocktake_id = t2.stocktake_id
```